# POST request not working in ASP, nothing happens

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

My post request is not working.  When I try to submit it after editing the form fields, the form fields go back to the original values and nothing happens.  The expected behavior is that after submission, the app should redirect to a different page and display the edited values.

This is the code from my Controller:

```
[Route("Cheese/Edit/{id}")]
public IActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    Cheese cheeseToEdit = CheeseData.GetById(id);
    ViewBag.cheese = cheeseToEdit;
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("/Cheese/Edit")]
public IActionResult Edit(int cheeseId, string name, string description)
{
    CheeseData.Edit(cheeseId, name, description);
    return Redirect("/Cheese");
}
```

This is the code from the form:

```html
<h1>Edit Cheese</h1>

<form method="post">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="name" id="name" type="text" value="@ViewBag.cheese.Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="description">Description</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="description" id="description" type="text" value="@ViewBag.cheese.Description" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">

        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="cheeseId" id="cheeseId" value="@ViewBag.cheese.CheeseId" />
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Add Cheese" />

</form>
```

This is the code from the CheeseData class that contains the Edit method that is used in the Edit post method

```
public class CheeseData
{
    static private List<Cheese> cheeses = new List<Cheese>();

    //GetAll
    public static List<Cheese> GetAll()
    {
        return cheeses;
    }

    //Add
    public static void Add(Cheese newCheese)
    {
        cheeses.Add(newCheese);
    }

    //Remove
    public static void Remove(int id)
    {
        Cheese cheeseToRemove = GetById(id);
        cheeses.Remove(cheeseToRemove);
    }

    public static void Edit(int id, string name, string description)
    {
        int index = CheeseData.GetAll().FindIndex(m => m.CheeseId == id);
        cheeses[index].Name = name;
        cheeses[index].Description = description;
    }

    //GetById
    public static Cheese GetById(int id)
    {
        //this is linq method syntax.  the Single method returns the one object from the
        //list that matches the criteria
        return cheeses.Single(x => x.CheeseId == id);
    } 
}
```

Comment: POSTs in MVC expect parameters to come from the body of the HTTP request, and by default, simple types are read from the querystring of the request. Try adding [FromBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody) to all of your parameters.

Comment: @KirkLarkin I added [HttpGet] to the first edit method and it works now.  Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: try to write the action you are going to EG:< form asp-action="_YourActionName"